# How can I define the first label I want to display in a chart's axis?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a chart:

[image]

I would like to change the X axis so that the first label is 201, not 1.  How can I define the first label I want to display in a chart's axis?

I went through the `format axis` menu, I haven't seen anything to offset the label:

[image]

[image]

I would prefer not to have to change the data.

I used Microsoft Excel 2013 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: I haven't found any solution yet.

Comment: Any idea is welcome.